# Calculate a variable based on length of run of specific value in R code

Tags: r, run-length-encoding

I have a data set like this,

```
 dat <- data.frame(d1=c(0,1,0,1,0),
      d2=c(0,1,1,1,0),d3=c(1,0,1,1,0),
      d4=c(1,0,0,0,0),d5=c(1,1,1,0,0))
 dat
  d1 d2 d3 d4 d5
1  0  0  1  1  1
2  1  1  0  0  1
3  0  1  1  0  1
4  1  1  1  0  0
5  0  0  0  0  0
```

If I consider each row is set of run for an individual. I want to calculate an indicator variable named "indicator" based on run. For example, individual 1 run is (0,0,1,1,1) for this backward length of run with value first 1's is 3. On the other hand, for individual 3 run is (0,1,1,0,1), backward length of run with value first 1,s is 1. Required data set is like this.

```
  d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 indicator
   0  0  1  1  1   3
   1  1  0  0  1   1
   0  1  1  0  1   1
   1  1  1  0  0   3 
   0  0  0  0  0   0
```

I have tried in this way,

```
    indicator <- NULL      
    for(i in 1:5){
        indicator[i] <- rev(sequence(rle(dat[i,])$lengths))[1]
     }
    indicator[1:5]
   cbind(dat, indicator=indicator[1:5])
```

But this gives data like this,

```
  d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 indicator
1  0  0  1  1  1         3
2  1  1  0  0  1         1
3  0  1  1  0  1         1
4  1  1  1  0  0         2
5  0  0  0  0  0         5
```

Could any body help me to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
val <- apply(dat, 1, function(x) with(rle(rev(x)==1), lengths[values])[1])
dat$indicator <- replace(val, is.na(val),0)
dat
#   d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 indicator
#1  0  0  1  1  1         3
#2  1  1  0  0  1         1
#3  0  1  1  0  1         1
#4  1  1  1  0  0         3
#5  0  0  0  0  0         0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
x = apply(rev(dat),1, function(u) ifelse(u[1]==1, match(0,u)-1, match(1,u)))
transform(dat, indicator = ifelse(is.na(x), 0,x))

#  d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 indicator
#1  0  0  1  1  1         3
#2  1  1  0  0  1         1
#3  0  1  1  0  1         1
#4  1  1  1  0  0         3
#5  0  0  0  0  0         0
```

Comment: True, I tried other solutions with a matrix for vectorized solution and kept the command! Edited.